# .axd custom handler is reachable through browser, but code using HttpWebRequest returns 404

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

In an ASP.NET webapp, I have a Custom Handler defined for .axd pages as such:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
      <add  verb="*" path="*.axd" name="MyAXDHandler" type="MyAXDHandler"/>
  </handlers>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

I can then hit urls like http://localhost/somename.axd from my browser (Chrome if it matters) succesfully. However, code like

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost/somename.axd");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
var response = request.GetResponse())
```

fails with a WebException (StatusCode 404) and, using a tool like wget also fails with a 404.

What is happening? How do I resolve it?